# Did any American political party have a legal personality anywhere at any time? Did it ever lapse?

Tags: united-states

After the War of Independence, some institutions such as the Bank of the United States were granted legal personality by the state or federal authorities. Of course, some of them ceased to exist (inc. the Bank), and lost their legal personality.

Did e.g. Jefferson's party (the Democrat-Republicans) ever have the status of a legally recognised entity, at either the state or federal level? Did it cease to have this status, before being resurrected by Jackson?

Edit: The point isn't which party it was; the question would be the same whether it was the Whig, Anti-Federalist, or any other.

Comment: No it's not. The point isn't what they called it; the question would be the same whether I used the term Jeffersonian, Anti-Federalist, or any other name.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of "expanding" the question. If you agree with the expanded version, I will retract my close vote as no longer being a duplicate.

Comment: Cool beans.....

Comment: Vote retracted. If we were starting from scratch, I might have advised you to post this only Politics SE, although it is on-topic here.

Comment: I find the wording ambiguous. `A legal person, in legal contexts often simply person, less ambiguously legal entity, is any human or non-human entity, in other words, any human being, firm, or government agency that is recognized as having legal rights and obligations, such as having the ability to enter into contracts, to sue, and to be sued.`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_person. If the Republican or Democratic parties can directly, say, pay for ads or hire some rooms at the Watergate or have bank accounts, they are legal persons.

Comment: But your question seems more about them having being *chartered* by a government, which would be a different concept.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on Politics.se, where it is already asked and answered:
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10074/what-type-of-organization-is-an-american-political-party See also [this](http://www.encyclopedia.com/politics/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/political-parties-constitutional-law)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Firstly, that answer on Politics SE only talks about the situation since 1971 - hardly an answer to this question. Secondly, does every question about history and politics belong on Politics SE? As far as I can see it's perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @SJuan76 Political parties today certainly appear to have [legal personalities](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G7sFDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22legal+personality%22+%22political+party%22+%22united+states%22&source=bl&ots=Scnp-gIVLh&sig=InOyYPzigtnqzefo6gt-_6u-l-c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKoPe7ztXVAhVIJFAKHQgvAhMQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=%22legal%20personality%22%20%22political%20party%22%20%22united%20states%22&f=false). The question is, did they have them then.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Unlike the other question we migrated that was grounded in "current events," this one really is grounded in history, IMHO.

Comment: Legal personality is the point here. In past times that was quite hard to obtain. Getting a charter was one way to do that.

Comment: I'll admit to not being a lawyer and thus not being familiar with the term "legal personality", but I suspect you may be [using it wrong](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/legal-personality.html). Can you rephrase not in legal jargon?

Comment: @TomAu Rather than trying to discuss it at length here, I've posted on [meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3496/24858)

Comment: Does a municipal charter from NYC count?

Comment: Nevermind. Tammany split off its political arm into a separate entity.